# Coworker may have maliciously fooled with PC, how do I leave the company safely?

Tags: software-industry, quitting, unprofessional-behavior, bullying

When I joined this company, I had the unfortunate experience of working with very jaded and unprofessional developers. They wanted me to work on their personal projects and hide my activity from IT by installing a different OS on a test machine that IT couldn't spy on. I declined, and wanted to focus on my real work instead. My reputation was smeared behind my back, I was lied to about projects, and set up for failure.

One of these developers named Bob, has the password to my work PC. He brought it to me from IT when I first started working there. He tried to make it seem like he was being helpful, but I am extremely suspicious. IT is also required to know our passwords. This guy works together with a family member, and is family friends with senior management in our office including the Chief engineer and head of security. The chief engineer and head of Security fired the IT guy, and promoted his friends to be the new IT guys, so he completely controls IT. This top dog is very informal and likes to tease people, so I doubt he take any concerns about bullying or IT violations seriously.

I am worried that Bob may have planted something on my PC, since he has my password. I never changed my password, since IT knows our passwords anyway. I do not doubt he could have gotten my password if I changed it.

If I report anything, I am unlikely to keep my job. I doubt management would risk disciplining and pissing off multiple developers and family friends. It would be easier to get rid of me.

How do I leave this company and minimize the liability of leaving behind a computer which may used against me in the future?

I work in the US and these guys work for the government.

Comment: How did he get your password? Was it all of them having personal projects - or is this something that you believe?

Comment: You ask way too many questions in one post and shut out most plausible answers as well. Voting to close as unclear what you're asking. Please edit the question to focus on exactly what help you need.

Comment: This is a terrible situation to be in - and there's really it's nothing to do but get out it and into a new job.

Comment: "IT is also required to know our passwords." - no they are not if they know what they are doing.

Comment: In fact IT should not know your passwords.

Comment: Change your password

Comment: "I am thinking of putting my concerns about bullying and IT policy violations in writing" - What does the IT policy say about changing passwords, and IT having access to them? You also seem to be incredibly paranoid about Bob, just because he brought you your PC from IT and gave you the initial password (which, by most policies, you would have been expected to change on first use anyway?)

Comment: "since he has my password, and tried to get me fired. I never changed my password, since IT is very informal and knows our passwords " What sort of mickey mouse IT is this?

Comment: Just change your password after IT assigns you one. They should have the power to *reset* your password if needed, not to know your password.

Comment: Do you also work for the US (or state) government? Is this a government workplace?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense.  If Bob is friendly with senior management, who installed their own IT people and is essentially in control of IT.  Why does he want you to do projects to "hide from IT"?

Comment: @DJClayworth I'm also curious about this. I'm pretty sure that these practices are not legal in US Government IT policy - in any department.

Comment: IT should never know your password. IT may have means to get into your computer or into an account of yours without your password, but they must never know your password. Go straight to IT, tell them that someone else has your password, and ask them what to do about it. It is an immense security risk to the company (because someone could think they can cause damage without being caught).

Comment: Incidentally, there is a Fraud, Waste, and Abuse hotline for things like this.

Answer (score 3):

I may get down-votes on my answer but I will answer as I work in the IT Security profession, and see fundamental security issues that are not addressed and present a real risk to you. There is also an implicit question which is very legitimate:

> "How do I protect myself while leaving the company"

First, at the company level, your firm is failing at the basics of computer security and operating using practices that will not fly in a regulated environment (such as the government) with a glaring example being the below statement:

> **IT is required to know our passwords.**

By the very fact that IT has the password to your computer means **they can impersonate you**. Any unscrupulous actions they take on the network will be traced directly back to you and there will be **no way for you deny the action as its your account that was used.** The fact that multiple other people can now use your account is immaterial, as in the audit logs, only your user ID will be associated with any changes, legitimate or malicious.

Some of your statements are also problematic. You state that these people work in government and that IT is very informal. Just because IT operates in a informal manner, as is often the culture of IT, **does not mean that security best practices are suddenly no longer applicable.**

> **I never changed my password anyway**

It should not even have been possible for you to have the choice in the first place. Good practice dictates that the password be changed upon first use by the assigned user.

As to how to protect yourself, you can request your machine be wiped before leaving which should sanitize the machine for the next user. In addition, keeping clear documentation of incidents such when you were requested to work on pet projects and by whom, rather than legitimate work protects you by keeping a paper trail on what was said.

**Overall, while you may not have much chance this time, the information above can be used if you ever face a similar situation in the future.**

Comment: It's quite the opposite if it is known that IT has your password - exactly because they _can_ impersonate you, that means nothing can be effectively traced back to you. That's why any decent IT department _doesn't_ know your password.

Comment: @Gnasher729 , check the edit I made. While multiple people can use his account, any actions taken by that account will be accounted for in audit logs under his single user ID.

Comment: @Anthony yes, but if the policy that IT knows his password is well known, i.e. if he can prove that this is the policy, then the user ID appearing in the logs doesn't hold as evidence against OP as IT could have impersonated him. Plausible deniability.